# db2 prune command procudes "DIA8701C Access denied for resource" error

Tags: backup, db2, db2-luw

On Db2 v11.5.8.0 on Linux/x86-64 couple of mouths ago we have moved our database from one Linux to another.
Every night at the time of backup error is written in db2diag.log file.

```
2023-08-16-02.14.13.540270+120 E19866377E1207        LEVEL: Error (OS)
PID     : 48681                TID : 140572366989056 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: myinst               NODE : 000            DB   : mydb
APPHDL  : 0-24364              APPID: *LOCAL.myinst.230816000503
AUTHID  : MXIN                 HOSTNAME: myhostname
EDUID   : 172                  EDUNAME: db2agent (mydb) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloopenp, probe:80
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x840F0001=-2079391743=SQLO_ACCD "Access Denied"
          DIA8701C Access denied for resource "", operating system return code 
          was "".
CALLED  : OS, -, open                             OSERR: EACCES (13)
DATA #1 : Codepath, 8 bytes
4:11:12:24:40
DATA #2 : File name, 63 bytes
/cifs/db2sd-db2prod/mydb.0.myinst.DBPART000.20230324020503.001
DATA #3 : SQO Open File Options, PD_TYPE_SQO_FILE_OPEN_OPTIONS, 4 bytes
SQLO_REVISE, SQLO_READWRITE, SQLO_EXCLUSIVE, SQLO_WRITETHRU
```

Like I see from shell script first command is "backup database..." and then second command is:

```
PRUNE HISTORY $(date -d -$PHISTORYday +"%Y%m%d") AND DELETE;
```

Prune command is the most likely candidate for this error. I know we used to store backups on /cifs/db2sd-db2prod directoy, but
we have new location for backup.

From the file name from error message "20230324020503.001" it looks like database is looking for 5 moths old backup file, probably at the stage of pruning, but can't find it, because path to this file does not exists anymore.

I would just like to have db2diag.log file as clean as possible. How to fix this problem?

Comment: I guess you'll need to force-prune all history prior to the date on which you moved the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UPDATE HISTORY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-list-history) command to mark the corresponding history entries as deleted.
You may use the following statement to generate the corresponding Db2 CLP commands.

```
SELECT 
--EID, SEQNUM, ENTRY_STATUS 
'UPDATE HISTORY EID ' || EID || ' WITH STATUS X'
FROM SYSIBMADM.DB_HISTORY 
WHERE OBJECTTYPE = 'D' AND OPERATION = 'B'
AND START_TIME = '20230324020503'
```

Don't use the `ADMIN_CMD` routine to run these statements - it does nothing at least on my Windows 11.5.7 version (it's probably some bug).